# Parse nested Json data into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, nested, json-value

I have a column `JsonObject` in the `t` table. I need to parse this `JsonObject` column which has JSON values in the array.

My first solution is:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_VALUE(JsonObject, '$.Id') AS Id,
    JSON_VALUE(JsonObject, '$.Provider') AS Provider,
    JSON_VALUE(JsonObject, '$.Messages[0].Sender') AS Sender,
    JSON_VALUE(JsonObject, '$.Messages[0].Text') AS Text
FROM
    dbo.t
```

This is just shown the first message of the provider but a provider has more than one messages. If I query as follow, it didn't give any of 'Messages' data

```
JSON_VALUE(JsonObject, '$.Messages.Sender') AS Sender,
JSON_VALUE(JsonObject, '$.Messages.Text') AS Text
```

Messages data is like:

```
{"Messages":[{"Sender":"John","Text":"xxxx"},{"Sender":"Peter","Text":"yyyy"}]}
```

How can I show every 'Messages' data in different rows with them 'Id' and 'Provider'?

Comment: Which DBMS?  BigQuery, PostgreSQL, etc?

Comment: I am trying to parse in MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [CROSS APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply) and [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  Like this:

```
declare @msg table(id int identity, msg nvarchar(max))
insert into @msg(msg) values ('{"Messages":[{"Sender":"John","Text":"xxxx"},{"Sender":"Peter","Text":"yyyy"}]}')
insert into @msg(msg) values ('{"Messages":[{"Sender":"Fred","Text":"xxxx"},{"Sender":"Akex","Text":"yyyy"}]}')


select m.id, parsedJson.*
from @msg m
cross apply openjson(m.msg,'$.Messages') 
with 
(
   Sender nvarchar(200),
   Text nvarchar(max)
) as parsedJson
```

outputs

```
id          Sender     Text
----------- ---------- -------------------
1           John       xxxx
1           Peter      yyyy
2           Fred       xxxx
2           Akex       yyyy
```

Comment: I have already a table in MSSQL. It has two columns 'Id' and  'JsonObject' which have JSON data. If I want to solve as you did, I can't declare a column of a table like @msg. 


It gives me an error : ""Must declare the scalar variable""

Comment: That's just an example.  Replace `@msg` with your existing table name.

Comment: Solved it. Thank you so much :)